# Boxplot.stats R not identifying outliers

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers

I have used boxplot.stats$out to get outliers of a list in R. However I noticed that many times it fails to identify outliers. For example:

```
list = c(3,4,7,500)
boxplot.stats(list)

$`stats`
[1]   3.0   3.5   5.5 253.5 500.0

$n
[1] 4

$conf
[1] -192  203

$out
numeric(0)

quantile(list)

    0%    25%    50%    75%   100% 
  3.00   3.75   5.50 130.25 500.00 

130.25+1.5*IQR(list) = 320
```

As you can see the boxplot.stats() function failed to find the outlier 500, even though when I looked at the documentation they are using the Q1/Q3+/-1.5*IQR method. So 500 should've been identified as an outlier, but it clearly is not finding it and I'm not sure why?

I have tried this with a list of 5 elements instead of 4, or with an outlier that is very small instead of very large and I still get the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the third number in the "stats" portion is 253.5,  not 130.25
The documentation for `boxplot.stats` says:

> The two ‘hinges’ are versions of the first and third quartile, i.e.,
>   close to quantile(x, c(1,3)/4). The hinges equal the quartiles for odd
>   n (where n <- length(x)) and differ for even n. Whereas the quartiles
>   only equal observations for n %% 4 == 1 (n = 1 mod 4), the hinges do
>   so additionally for n %% 4 == 2 (n = 2 mod 4), and are in the middle
>   of two observations otherwise

In other words, for your data, it is using `(500+7)/2` as the Q3 value
(and incidentally `(3+4)/2 = 3.5` as Q1,  not the 3.75 that you got from 
`quantile`).  Boxplot will use the boundary `253.5 + 1.5*(253.5 - 3.5) = 628.5`

Comment: Thanks that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

If you read the help page `help("boxplot.stats")` carefully, the return value section says the following. My emphasis.

> stats
>      a vector of length 5, containing the extreme of the lower
>      whisker, the lower ‘hinge’, the median, the upper ‘hinge’ and
>      **the extreme of the upper whisker**.

Then, in the same section, again my emphasis.

> out
>       the values of any data points which lie beyond the 
>       **extremes of the whiskers** (if(do.out)).

Your data has 4 points. The **extreme of the upper whisker**, as returned in list member `$stats`, is `500.0`, and this is the maximum of your data. There is no error.

Comment: I tried this with n=5 and n=10 and still get similar problems, but the answer above makes sense because it's not calculating the outliers purely based on 1.5*IQR

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```r
library (car)
Boxplot (Petal.Length ~ Species, id = list (n=Inf))
```

to identify all the outliers